# How to animate a VectorDrawable in a fluid-like manner?

Tags: android, animation, android-vectordrawable

### Background

Suppose I have a VectorDrawable that look like a top->down arrow:

[image]

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:pathData="M20,12l-1.41,-1.41L13,16.17V4h-2v12.17l-5.58,-5.59L4,12l8,8 8,-8z"
        android:fillColor="#010101"/>
</vector>
```

I want to show an animation of it that looks like a fluid that it poured, so that first nothing is shown, then the top area, then also the mid area, and then the bottom. After all is shown, it begins to hide, so that the top gets hidden, and then the mid, and then the bottom.

Here's a sketch of what I mean:

[image]

### The problem

There are some tutorials about VectorDrawable animations, and it seems they require a lot of vector understanding, without an easy way to do such a thing.

### What I've found

I've found a tool to use for this, but I don't understand how to use it, and the examples link is currently broken :

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidIconAnimator/

I've also found some tutorials about VectorDrawable animations in general, but I can't find this specific animation explanation:

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html

This link in particular has a clue about what I should use. I think I should use "trimPathStart", "trimPathEnd", "trimPathOffset", or maybe "clip-path" .

The example animation they have there shows that it might be it:
[image]

But I can't find how to do it.

### The question

How can I apply such an animation on the VectorDrawable?

Will it work on old Android versions too, using the support library?

---

EDIT:
I've succeeded animating the arrow, but it has 2 issues:

1. Because it's a single path, it doesn't look well. It need to know how to split it into 3 paths, so that each will animate nicely.
2. It seems all I use in the code is from API 21 and above. I did it by looking at the link I wrote before (here), and need to know how to support older versions.

Here's the code:

**res/drawable/vector_animation.xml**

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_darkblue_arrow">

    <target android:name="a_stroke">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="5000"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="1300"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>


</animated-vector>
```

**res/drawable/vector.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:name="a_stroke"
        android:fillColor="#010101"
        android:pathData="M20,12l-1.41,-1.41L13,16.17V4h-2v12.17l-5.58,-5.59L4,12l8,8 8,-8z"/>
</vector>
```

**res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/vector_animation"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Animatable cursiveAvd = ((Animatable) ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)).getDrawable());
        cursiveAvd.stop();
        cursiveAvd.start();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:
I made a simple 3-paths arrow VectorDrawable, and succeeded animating it.

Here's the VectorDrawable I created:

**ic_drawing.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="210dp"
        android:height="297dp"
        android:viewportHeight="1052.3622"
        android:viewportWidth="744.0945">
    <path
        android:name="main_line"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M742.6,9.7C313,-8.4 316.2,860.8 316.2,860.8"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeLineJoin="miter"
        android:strokeWidth="5.32507801"/>
    <path
        android:name="left_line"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="m314.3,846.6c-211.4,-254.3 -160,-294.3 -160,-294.3"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeLineJoin="miter"
        android:strokeWidth="5"/>
    <path
        android:name="right_line"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M320,843.8C364.2,751.2 437.4,670.7 471.4,566.6"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeLineJoin="miter"
        android:strokeWidth="5"/>
</vector>
```

**vector_animation2.xml**

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_drawing">

    <target android:name="main_line">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="5000"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="1300"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="left_line">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                android:startDelay="5000"
                android:duration="5000"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="1300"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="right_line">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                android:startDelay="5000"
                android:duration="5000"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="1300"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>

</animated-vector>
```

So, it works nicely, but works only on newer versions of Android, and I still would like to know how to split existing VectorDrawable nicely, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: i didn't try it myself, but it seems the easiest way to create that kind of animations is [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android). As per backward compatibility - [yes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution), it works with support library

Comment: @Divers We don't work with "Adobe After Effects". The question is about VectorDrawable.

Comment: You were asking for easy way - I gave it to you, but if you want to do it manually, then probably you should spend some time reading [tutorials](https://lewismcgeary.github.io/posts/animated-vector-drawable-pathMorphing/) and implement it yourself. Answers on both of your questions is YES.

Comment: @Divers I am not a designer and don't own this app. Even the designer we have don't work with this app.

Comment: Roman Nurik's tool is pretty strait forward, seems you should just have several "slides" of animations and upload it there. It will build transitions.

Comment: @Divers I've succeeded using it (after modifying the VectorDrawable to have 3 paths instead of 1), but the generated file only works on new Android versions. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post resulting xml file?

Comment: @Divers As I wrote the comment, I also updated the question with the newer code :)

Comment: Good progress! This should be suitable for support library, you just need to use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src` in your ImageView and ensure you've followed the normal steps to enable the vector support in your gradle file ( `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` )

Comment: There's a simpler way,
we can use https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath
to do these types of animation.

Comment: @Tarek360 Also cool. Please show how to use it in an answer.

Comment: Full example here https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to get a similar look, however not all are going to be backwards compatible using the support library. For that reason I'd recommend using `trimPathStart` and `trimPathEnd`.

I'll describe the approach I would take, rather than the final solution(can be time consuming!).

The first problem in getting started is that your original VectorDrawable isn't really suitable for this type of animation!

The drawable in the question describes the outline of the shape(ie. the nine lines outlining the arrow) and displays the fill. What would be better for our purposes would be to have a drawable made up of three lines where there is no `fillColor` and instead we set how the lines should display using `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth`.

This should be a simple VectorDrawable with three `<path>` elements: one for the vertical line, and one each for the sides of the arrow head.

Once you have this you can think about how you want your animation to look. `trimPathStart` and `trimPathEnd` should be values between 0 and 1 where 0 is the start of the path and 1 is the end. Consider the vertical line drawn from top to bottom:

`trimPathStart="0"` `trimPathEnd="0"` --we can't see the line

-> animate to

`trimPathStart="0"` `trimPathEnd="1"` --we've drawn the line from top to bottom

-> animate to

`trimPathStart="1"` `trimPathEnd="1"` --we've made the line disappear again by moving the starting point from top to bottom

You would do a similar thing with each side of the arrow and order things as appropriate to get your desired effect.

Comment: OK, for now I've done it on the single-part vector. I've updated the answer, but how can I split the path into 3 paths nicely, and also make it work on pre-API-21 ?